# Implementation of CenteredTabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-tablayout

I need something like TabLayout with scrolling and selecting central tab with corresponding ViewPager performance attached to it.
I've tried solve this problem by writing next code but it seems quite glitchy. I'm sure there is other way to solve this problem.

```
public class CenteredTabLayout extends TabLayout {


   public ViewPager mViewPager;
    private int currentWidthOffset = 0;
    private int index = 0;
    private int totalElementsNumber;
    private ArrayList<Integer> elementsWidth = new ArrayList<>();
    private volatile int state = 2;

    public CenteredTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenteredTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CenteredTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab) {
        getElementsWidth();
        super.addTab(tab);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTab(Tab tab) {
        getElementsWidth();
        super.removeTab(tab);

    }

    private void getElementsWidth() {
        elementsWidth.clear();
        totalElementsNumber = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildCount();
        //Log.i(ScrollableTabsActivityCustom1.TAG, "totalElementsNumber = " + totalElementsNumber);
        for(int i = 0; i < totalElementsNumber; i++) {
            elementsWidth.add(((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i).getWidth());
            //Log.i(ScrollableTabsActivityCustom1.TAG, "elementsWidth.get(i) = " + elementsWidth.get(i));
        }
    }

    CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i(ScrollableTabsActivityCustom1.TAG, "finished");
            View tab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(index);
            scrollTo(currentWidthOffset , 0); 
        }
    };

    private void startTimer(final int currentState) {
        if(currentState != state) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    state = currentState;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException pE) {
                        pE.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
                    state = 2;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        getElementsWidth();
        int difference = l - oldl;
        int currentWidthOffsetSave = currentWidthOffset;

        if(state != 1 && difference > 0 && l > (currentWidthOffset + elementsWidth.get(checkIndex(index)) / 2)) {
            do {
                currentWidthOffset += elementsWidth.get(checkIndex(index));
                index++;
                index = checkIndex(index);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
                View tab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(index);
                scrollTo(currentWidthOffset, 0);
            } while(currentWidthOffsetSave + difference > currentWidthOffset + elementsWidth.get(checkIndex(index)) / 2);

            if(difference > 10) {
                startTimer(0);
            }
        }

        if(state != 0 && difference < 0 && l < (currentWidthOffset - elementsWidth.get(checkIndex(index - 1)) / 2)) {

            do {
                index--;
                index = checkIndex(index);
                currentWidthOffset -= elementsWidth.get(index);
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
                scrollTo(currentWidthOffset, 0);
            } while(currentWidthOffsetSave - difference < currentWidthOffset - elementsWidth.get(checkIndex(index)) / 2);

            if(difference < 10) {
                startTimer(1);
            }
        }
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mCountDownTimer.start();
    }

    private int checkIndex(int index) {
        if(index < 0) {

            index = 0;
        }
        if(index > totalElementsNumber - 1) {
            index = totalElementsNumber - 1;
        }
        return index;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        View firstTab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
        View lastTab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildCount() - 1);
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(getChildAt(0), (getWidth() / 2) - (firstTab.getWidth() / 2), 0, (getWidth() / 2) - (lastTab.getWidth() / 2) , 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you want the tab selected should always be in the center ??

Comment: Yes, always centered and TabLayout scrolling should lead to according PageViewer scrolling, and also scroll should be smooth. Is there any out of box solution? Because my solution is not so good and it needs additional work around.